# Can not pass data/parameter to an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple web page with a dropdown and a partial view. I am trying to update the partial view based on the result of the ajax call initiated when the dropdown selectedvalue changes. I can reach the controller action, but the parameter I am passing is always null.

I have tried the following ways to pass the data.

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Id', managerId)

    data:formData,
    data: { 'Id': managerId } ,
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'Id': managerId } ),
```

Here is the Controller Action. I use the default MVC routing, there are no other routing defined.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetEmployees(string Id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
        {
            Id = "2";
        }
        long numberId = Convert.ToInt64(Id);
        List<SEmployee> lstEmp = db.SEmployees.Where(x => x.LkupParentManagerId == numberId).ToList();
        return PartialView("_EmployeeTable", lstEmp);
    }
```

Here is the complete Ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#ddManager").change(function () {
    var managerId = this.value;
    var formData = new FormData();
    var form = $('form').serialize();
    formData.append('Id', managerId);
    //alert(managerId);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/SEmployees/GetEmployees",
        type: 'POST',
        data:formData,
        //data: { 'Id': managerId } ,
        //data: JSON.stringify({ 'Id': managerId } ),
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            //alert(result);
            $("#tblEmployees").html(result);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Failed to retrieve the Employees.');
        }
    });
});
```

});

Here is the dropdown in the view.

```
    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label required" })
            <div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedId, Model.LstSelectManagers, new { @id = "ddManager", @class = "form-control", @margin = "auto" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedId, "", new { @class = "text-danger", AutoPostBack = "True" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have tried the above three different ways to pass the data from view to controller. The call goes to the controller, but not the data. Please help me troubleshooting the ajax call. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for your ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/SEmployees/GetEmployees/" + managerId,
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    success: function (result) {
        //alert(result);
        $("#tblEmployees").html(result);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Failed to retrieve the Employees.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for this scenario. But what if I were passing multiple parameters, I would like to understand how to pass any data to the action using the data parameter.

Comment: You can stringify them using `JSON.stringify` like `data: JSON.stringify({data:d})` and send to the controller, also make sure that the controller is set to accept the data. for instance if you are strigifying `{user:'johndoe', pass:'Pass'}`, the controller parameter must have attributes `user` and `pass`