# Can you call a function from a Controller using @Html.DropDownList onchange?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

Say I have

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> View()
        {
            ViewData["Employee"] = new SelectList(_userManager.Users.ToList(), "Id", "FullName");
            List<ScreenshotItem> screenshotItems = await _context.ScreenshotItems.ToListAsync();
            ScreenshotViewModel model = new ScreenshotViewModel();
            model.ScreenshotItems = screenshotItems;
            return View(model);
        }
```

And then I simply display the images:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Id", (SelectList) ViewBag.Employee, new {onchange = "View()"}))

@foreach (var ss in Model.ScreenshotItems)
{
    <div>
        <img src="@ss.Path" alt="@ss.Path"/>
        <label>@ss.EmployeeId</label>
    </div>
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is I want to filter the list using a DropDownList, so on every change of the dropdownlist I want the list to be updated. Is this possible?

Comment: onchange() is not a server side event, you can use Ajax to call the method in the controller. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779322/can-not-pass-data-parameter-to-an-ajax-call/56779767#56779767)

Comment: *Is this possible* yes but you need to use Javascript, you can't do this just using the MVC framework

Comment: Using Javascript onChange event for your drop-down will be the best idea in your case here.

Answer (score 1):

According to your ViewModel, in your View you'll have some thing like this:

```
@using Project.Path.To.Your.ScreenshotViewModel
@model ScreenshotViewModel


@{

List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
Model.ScreenshotItems.ToList().ForEach(x => {
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.EmployeeName, Value = x.EmployeeId.ToString()   });
    });

    @Html.DropDownList("selectList", listItems, new { @onchange = "foo()" })

    <ul id="UList">
        @foreach (var i in Model.ScreenshotItems)
        {
            <li  tagValue="@i.EmployeeId">
                 <img src="@i.Path" alt="@i.Path"/>
                 <label>@i.EmployeeName</label>
            </li>
        }            
    </ul>
 }
```

and, at the bottom of that view, you can add or bundle this javascript code:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function foo() {
            var empName = $("select#selectList :selected").text();
            var empID = $("select#selectList :selected").val();
            //alert(empName);

            $('ul#UList').find('li').each(function (index, el) {
                //alert($(this).attr('tagValue'));
                $(this).attr('tagValue') == empID ? $(this).removeClass('hidden') : $(this).addClass('hidden');
            });
        }
    </script>
```

You will customize this code wherever needed. For instance, It's a better idea to use department ID as for 'tagValue' attribute, so that you can filter all Employees belonging to a specific department, by selecting the department name from the drop down. In addition, you may change `<ul><li>` tags to nested `<div>`s with same class attribute. Don't forget to include bootstrap.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry I got busy. While this does work, I cannot mark it as the answer I'm looking for. This is what I've been doing. What I'm looking for is something that doesn't involve and scripting. Thanks tho!